# Showing Editors on click of a node in Xtratreelist

Tags: devexpress, xtratreelist

I am using the latest version of DevExpress XtratreeList and have a requirement of showing editors on click of each node on the tree. Please see this screenshot http://community.devexpress.com/forums/p/89574/310095.aspx

I am wondering how i can dynamically save and render a specific editor(rather a form) per node on the treelist. Clicking on "Friends" in the screenshot should bring up a different editor as compared to clicking on "Parties". Also, if a user tries to add more objects on the editor for Parties/Friends like say a Textbox/Listbox, it should be saved and come up fine when i click the nodes. Does anyone have ideas regarding how do i dynamically bring up different editors on click of a random node on the lefT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by handling the TreeList's [FocusedNodeChanged](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraTreeListTreeList_FocusedNodeChangedtopic) event.  All you need to do is to determine the current FocusedNode and [its values](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5639) and show the required editor.